# regex trailing letters+numbers+symbols

Tags: regex

I have the following set of texts:

```
msg_type_add=ADD
table_name_card=cardholder
bin_card=7771800
member_card=123
card_status_active=123
card_status_cancelled=123
```

I would like to match the trailing letters ,numbers and symbol after the '=' symbol.

How would i match it with a regex expression.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: we can do something like :  #[=][0-9]+$#

Answer (score 1):

You could match on:

```
[^=]+$
```

This would match the trailing portion after the equals sign.